# I want to use one image url to display other random images

Tags: php, html, image, random

I have seen this done before so I know for sure that it can be done -- however I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Using one image url like this one: http://website.com/imagefile.jpg

whenever this image url is accessed via a browser address bar or within a script or on a webpage it will display a different image: imagea.jpg, imageb.png, imagec.gif, etc. etc.

If anyone can help me figure this out using java script or php that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: No -- I have just been crawling the internet looking for similar functions to a solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice PHP script that I found: http://ma.tt/scripts/randomimage/
You link your image src to this PHP script and it will rotate through the images you have in the defined folder.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for -- it rotates the images itself -- the rotation has to use one image URL and rotate the images no matter where I add the image URL

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you be more clear of what you need?